# How to apply an angular directive to the div with .modal-dialog class?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

The problem that by documentation my modal template contain .modal-header, .modal-body and .modal-footer elements. I can't define whole modal template, since ngx modal automatically wraps the content into .modal-content>.modal-dialog.

I tried to apply directive with class selector, but this is also not working, since I think ngx module doesn't know anything about my module where the directive declared and exported.

I looking for may be some options to be able to define whole template of modal and other way to apply directive to the .modal-dialog level.

To be more specific I have create directive to make the modal draggable and I need to apply it exactly to the .modal-dialog level

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet should be using the directive ngx-bootstrap provide.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="staticModal.show()">Static modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" bsModal #staticModal="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: 'static'}"
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-static-name">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 id="dialog-static-name" class="modal-title pull-left">Static modal</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="staticModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is static modal, backdrop click will not close it.
        Click <b>&times;</b> to close modal.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I sow this section of the documentation. However I'd like to user service approach and user components as a templates. This is much more applicable from the application design point...

Comment: You would need to either customize the code base from ngx-bootstrap or use document API's like nativeElement.querySelector which might not be supported in Angular Universal.

Comment: I am not using server side rendering. When you talking about nativeElement.querySelector, you mean I can apply directive to .modal-header for example and query a parent node?

Comment: Yes getting the parent from child is possible but there isn't any built-in method for a general class selector, only childNode.parentNode. Wrapping your modal with a parent node with a custom directive, then accessing elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector would work better.